# how can I implement this Custom code in FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm trying to build a local media gallery kind of app with FlutterFlow, I want to display photos and videos from local storage. I did some research and I got this code but I'm new to this and I wanna learn how can I implement all this code into FlutterFlow the best way possible or if there's anoher way to dot it using FF widgets with some custom code for functionality ??

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:photo_gallery/photo_gallery.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'package:appinio_video_player/appinio_video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Album>? _albums;
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    initAsync();
  }

  Future<void> initAsync() async {
    if (await _promptPermissionSetting()) {
      List<Album> albums = await PhotoGallery.listAlbums();
      setState(() {
        _albums = albums;
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _promptPermissionSetting() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted || await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted ||
          await Permission.photos.request().isGranted &&
              await Permission.videos.request().isGranted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Photo gallery example'),
        ),
        body: _loading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  double gridWidth = (constraints.maxWidth - 20) / 3;
                  double gridHeight = gridWidth + 33;
                  double ratio = gridWidth / gridHeight;
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      childAspectRatio: ratio,
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ...?_albums?.map(
                          (album) => GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlbumPage(album)),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                    height: gridWidth,
                                    width: gridWidth,
                                    child: FadeInImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                                      image: AlbumThumbnailProvider(
                                        album: album,
                                        highQuality: true,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),  //Image thumbnail
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    album.name ?? "Unnamed Album",
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      height: 1.2,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),   //Album name
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    album.count.toString(),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      height: 1.2,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),  //Iterms count
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AlbumPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Album album;

  AlbumPage(Album album) : album = album;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AlbumPageState();
}

class AlbumPageState extends State<AlbumPage> {
  List<Medium>? _media;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAsync();
  }

  void initAsync() async {
    MediaPage mediaPage = await widget.album.listMedia();
    setState(() {
      _media = mediaPage.items;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Text(widget.album.name ?? "Unnamed Album"),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            ...?_media?.map(
              (medium) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewerPage(medium)),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: FadeInImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                    image: ThumbnailProvider(
                      mediumId: medium.id,
                      mediumType: medium.mediumType,
                      highQuality: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ViewerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Medium medium;

  ViewerPage(Medium medium) : medium = medium;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime? date = medium.creationDate ?? medium.modifiedDate;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          ),
          title: date != null ? Text(date.toLocal().toString()) : null,
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: medium.mediumType == MediumType.image
              ? GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    PhotoGallery.deleteMedium(mediumId: medium.id);
                  },
                  child: FadeInImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                    image: PhotoProvider(mediumId: medium.id),
                  ),
                )
              : Center(
                child: VideoProvider(
                    mediumId: medium.id,
                  ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class VideoProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mediumId;

  const VideoProvider({
    required this.mediumId,
  });

  @override
  _VideoProviderState createState() => _VideoProviderState();
}

class _VideoProviderState extends State<VideoProvider> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  late CustomVideoPlayerController _customVideoPlayerController;
  File? _file;
  bool initialized = false;

  final CustomVideoPlayerSettings _customVideoPlayerSettings =
  const CustomVideoPlayerSettings(showSeekButtons: false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAsync(); // Initialize the video player in initState
  }

  Future<void> initAsync() async {
    try {
      _file = await PhotoGallery.getFile(mediumId: widget.mediumId);
      _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_file!);
      await _videoPlayerController.initialize();

      _customVideoPlayerController = CustomVideoPlayerController(
        context: context,
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        customVideoPlayerSettings: _customVideoPlayerSettings,
        additionalVideoSources: {
          "Max": _videoPlayerController,
        },
      );

      setState(() {
        initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed : $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _customVideoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!initialized) {
      return CupertinoActivityIndicator(); // Show loading indicator until initialized
    }

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomVideoPlayer(
              customVideoPlayerController: _customVideoPlayerController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to do it but cuz I'm new to flutter and flutterflow I wasn't able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a [custom widget](https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/custom-functions/custom-widgets).

Every widget in FlutterFlow is stateful, so you can pretty much reuse all the code there. You just need to return the widgets returned by the `Widget build(BuildContext context)` functions and they will be available for use.

You can write whatever additional code you need to in the custom widget.

Here is an example of a custom widget I wrote to display version info from the package_info_plus library on a card, maybe it can inspire you:

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/schema/enums/enums.dart';
import '/backend/supabase/supabase.dart';
import '/actions/actions.dart' as action_blocks;
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

class AppVersionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppVersionWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.rightAligned,
    required this.centreAligned,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final bool rightAligned;
  final bool centreAligned;

  @override
  _AppVersionWidgetState createState() => _AppVersionWidgetState();
}

class _AppVersionWidgetState extends State<AppVersionWidget> {
  PackageInfo _packageInfo = PackageInfo(
    appName: 'unknown',
    packageName: 'unknown',
    version: 'unknown',
    buildNumber: 'unknown',
    buildSignature: 'unknown',
    installerStore: 'unknown',
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPackageInfo();
  }

  Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: widget.centreAligned
            ? CrossAxisAlignment.center
            : widget.rightAligned
                ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Build Version',
            textAlign: widget.centreAligned
                ? TextAlign.center
                : widget.rightAligned
                    ? TextAlign.right
                    : TextAlign.left,
            style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).labelLarge,
          ),
          Text(
            '${_packageInfo.version} (${_packageInfo.buildNumber})',
            textAlign: widget.centreAligned
                ? TextAlign.center
                : widget.rightAligned
                    ? TextAlign.right
                    : TextAlign.left,
            style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodySmall,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```